# Inherit indentation when using cat in bash function to print multiple lines

Tags: bash, cat

In the middle of doing `cat <<`, if we invoke a bash function that uses `cat <<` as well, the indentation is only inherited for the first line.

This is better explained using a simple example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

write_multiple_lines() {
    cat <<_EOF_
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
_EOF_
    return
}

cat << _EOF_
<html>
    $(write_multiple_lines)
</html>
_EOF_
```

The result is as follows (the `<p>` doesn't follow `<h1>`'s indentation).

```
<html>
    <h1>Header</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</html>
```

while the desired result is

```
<html>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</html>
```

I was expecting the indentation would be inherited if `cat <<` is used. Is there any workaround for this (other than manually adding indentation to subsequent lines as pointed out by @bob dylan in the comment)?

Comment: Add the indentations to the p line e.g. `    <p>Paragraph</p>` this

Comment: Yes I know, but I think there might be some "better" way.

Comment: Parameterize `write_multiple_lines` with the amount of indentation desired. That function has no idea about its position in the here document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to 'preserve' it is to change your input file. The reason why `<p>` is indented is because you've indented it here:

```
$(write_multiple_lines)
```

Since you don't want to change your input e.g.

```
write_multiple_lines() {
    cat <<_EOF_
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
_EOF_
    return
}
```

You could change it to echo the spaces for you and then print each line e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

write_multiple_lines() {
while read p; do
  echo "    " "$p"
done <<_EOF_
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
_EOF_
return
}

cat << _EOF_
<html>
$(write_multiple_lines)
</html>
_EOF_
```

output:

```
<html>
     <h1>Header</h1>
     <p>Paragraph</p>
</html>
```

Though this is less dynamic / obvious then if you formatted it verbatim so I'd stick by my original suggestion before doing something like this.